# Usage of iteration element within name pattern

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I would like to iterate with a for loop trough a list applying the following function to all list elements:

```
new_x = do.call("rbind",mget(ls(pattern = "^x.*")))
```

where `x` is a certain name pattern of a dataframe.
How do I iterate through a list where the list element `i` is the name pattern for my function?
The goal would be to get something like this:

```
for (i in filenames){
  i = do.call("rbind",mget(ls(pattern = "^i.*")))
}
```

So my question is basically how to use `i` within a name pattern, so I'm able to use the loop to rbind togerther seperate parts of a dataframe `xpart1`, `xpart2`, `xpart3` to `x`; `ypart1`, `ypart2`, `ypart3` to `y` and so on....

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can check my update.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using a `for` loop, then an option

```
v1 <- ls(pattern = "^x.*")
lst1 <- vector('list', length(v1))
for(i in seq_along(v1)){
        lst1[[i]] <- get(v1[i])
    }

do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

---

Or if we need to use `i` to create the `pattern`, we can use `paste`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', length(filenames))
names(lst1) <- filenames
for(i in filenames){
       lst1[[i]] <- get(ls(pattern = paste0(i, ".*")))
 }
do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

NOTE: `get` returns the value of a single object, whereas `mget` returns more than one object in a `list`.  If we use `for` loop, we assume that it is returning one object within the loop and `get` is only needed

---

Based on the OP's clarification, we can also use `mget`

```
xs <- paste0("xpart", 1:100)
ys <- paste0("ypart", 1:100)
xsdat <- do.call(rbind, mget(xs))
ysdat <- do.call(rbind, mget(ys))
```

Comment: The problem is, that ```x``` in the name pattern ```pattern = "^x.*"``` changes around n=100 times.
Basically I want to use this loop to rbind togerther seperate parts of a dataframe ```xpart1```,  ```xpart2```, ```xpart3``` to ```x```;```ypart1```,  ```ypart2```, ```ypart3``` to ```y``` and so on

Comment: @Mcgroger  I updated the post.  Based on your first code, `do.call("rbind",mget(ls(pattern = "^x.*")))`, it was not clear to me.